# ExtJS 4.2.1 Grouping feature bug

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, grouping, extjs4.2

Bug in ExtJS 4.2.1 Grouping feature

Try to ([Sencha Documentation page](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping) --> Live Preview):

1. Collapse first group "Accounting"
2. Try to select random row in other groups by mouse ("Dwight Schrute" for example)
3. Look which row becomes selected

Same thing in [Summary Grid Example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/example/grid/group-summary-grid.html):

If first group is collapsed - there is no chance to select row from other groups.

Somebody knows how to resolve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you upgrade or fix it using 4.2.1 ?

Comment: Upgrade to 4.2.2 fixed the problem. And nothing else was broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in ExtJS 4.2.2. Look in the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping) and in the [example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example/grid/group-summary-grid.html). Upgrade would be the best solution.

I don't know if it is practical for you to upgrade ?

If you cannot update, maybe you can find the bug comparing the 4.2.1 and 4.2.2 code?

Comment: Ok. I agreee. Upgrade to 4.2.2 is the best and fastest solution. Hope it do not bring new bugs for my working code.